# How to detect HTTP response status code and set a proxy accordingly in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

Is there a way to set a new proxy ip (e.g.: from a pool) according to the HTTP response status code?
For example, start up with an IP form an IP list till it gets a 503 response (or another http error code), then use the next one till it gets blocked，and so on, something like:

```
if http_status_code in [403, 503, ..., n]:
    proxy_ip = 'new ip'
    # Then keep using it till it's gets another error code
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy has a downloader middleware which is enabled by default to handle proxies. It's called [HTTP Proxy Middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware) and what it does is allows you to supply meta key `proxy` to your `Request` and use that proxy for this request.

There are few ways of doing this.
First one, straight-forward just use it in your spider code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    if response.status in range(400, 600):
        return Request(response.url, 
                       meta={'proxy': 'http://myproxy:8010'}
                       dont_filter=True)  # you need to ignore filtering because you already did one request to this url
```

Another more elegant way would be to use custom downloader middleware which would handle this for multiple callbacks and keep your spider code cleaner:

```
from project.settings import PROXY_URL
class MyDM(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if response.status in range(400, 600):
            logging.debug('retrying [{}]{} with proxy: {}'.format(response.status, response.url, PROXY_URL)
            return Request(response.url, 
                           meta={'proxy': PROXY_URL}
                           dont_filter=True)
        return response
```

Note that by default scrapy doesn't let through any response codes other than `200` ones. Scrapy automatically handles redirect codes `300` with `Redirect middleware` and raises request errors on `400` and `500` with HttpError middleware. To handle requests other than 200 you need to either:

Specify that in Request Meta:

```
Request(url, meta={'handle_httpstatus_list': [404,505]})
# or for all 
Request(url, meta={'handle_httpstatus_all': True})
```

Set a project/spider wide parameters:

```
HTTPERROR_ALLOW_ALL = True  # for all
HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES = [404, 505]  # for specific
```

as per http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#httperror-allowed-codes

Comment: It does not catch any HTTP status code except `200`!

Comment: @XO39 Correct, by default scrapy does not allow any responses other than `200` through. See my edit for more details :)

Comment: But what if I don't want to handle them only to detect them? I mean all I want is just to change the ip when one of these error codes is met! Can I do that with out handling them this way? the documentation says: _Keep in mind, however, that it’s usually a **bad idea** to handle **non-200** responses, unless you really know what you’re doing._

Comment: Hmm I guess you can override `Http Proxy middleware` and use it instead of the default one. In it you could define rules to change proxies based on response codes but you would **still** have to modify the response/request since you want to retry the failed requests in with a new proxy and because of asynchronious nature of scrapy a bunch of requests with old proxy would remain in the queue that would need to be modified too, so there's no way of getting around this modification issue.

Comment: @XO39 However one idea would be to rearrange the order of the default middlewares to have your proxy middleware before http error middleware so you wouldn't need to handle the response codes.
I'm not sure how safe that is but you can always try!:)

Comment: All the urls of the pages to be crawled are stored in a database, and they will extracted one by one, that solves the asynchronous issue. The only issue I'm still having is detecting the http response codes, in order to switch to another proxy when the first one gets blocked.